# laptop with good memory

Tags: laptop

I am a .net developer. I need laptop with 32GB ram with screen size 14 inch minimum.  I will have sql server 2017, Visual studio 2017. 
Does anyone has good recommendations on this? Weight should not be more than 2kg. Any recommendations on buying virtual machines than can always connect to VPN? What does this VM costs? What about Docker? I am really going crazy with search for 32GB ram. Please help

Comment: Do you have any more requirements for the hardware?  How many VMs will you be running at one time? Will you be gaming with this laptop? What is your budget?

Comment: Also, We only recommend hardware here. There is a [software recommendations site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) that you can ask about what VM software to run on this laptop, but you will need to show prior research and have a good list of requirements.

Comment: @Cfinley i am not going to run any VM. I am going to install everything on my laptop

Comment: Then I am confused about the statements about VMs in your question. Can you please elaborate on them?

Comment: @Cfinley I just asked if i can use VM as alternative and what is costs? my vm needs to be connected to vpn

Answer (score 2):

About your software questions, as commented, they belong on different sites.

To your question. If you are willing to pay you can certainly find a lot of laptop options that have 32 GB RAM.

One example is this [HP Envy 15t](https://goo.gl/zzfQ3p), that has a 7th gen i7, 32 GB of RAM, a 512 SSD drive + a 1 TB HDD, and a 4K display.